# Chrome Extensions - Donwload File in Specific Path

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extensions and I need to download file in specific path, i'm using chrome.download in background.js

```
chrome.downloads.download({
    url: request.url,
    filename: "teste.txt", // Optional
    saveAs: false,
 });
```

But, in this way, I have to choice the path in modal of download, but i need to define a specific path for download all files of this extensions!

How can I do it ?

Manifest:

```
"version": "1",
"manifest_version": 3,
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
},
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["jquery.js", "content.js"]
}],
"permissions": ["tabs", "browsingData", "activeTab", "downloads", "fileSystem"]
```

Comment: You can specify a relative path in `filename`.

Comment: I try "C:/Teste/teste.txt" and "~/Documents/Teste/teste.txt" and not work

Comment: These aren't relative paths. These are absolute paths. A relative path means `foo/file.txt` and it'll be created inside the downloads directory, not outside.

Comment: But i need to create inside C:/ path, in specific path

Comment: You can't do it via downloads. You'll have to write a separate app and call it via nativeMessaging.